# Frustration with an index/match query in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm throwing together a risk assessment/treatment Excel book, have built an index/match formula to pull the relevant 'Likelihood' & 'Seriousness' columns and provide the applicable score from a matrix on another sheet. The query appears to work fine for all but one column and I'm at a loss.

Any input would be greatly received.

The formula in question:
=INDEX(Scoring!$E$5:$J$9,MATCH($C7,Scoring!$E$4:$J$4,0),MATCH($D7,Scoring!$D$5:$D$9,0))

Note please that this is from the specific #REF! failure as seen in the below screenshot, but all the column E cells are using the exact same formula; and it only goes to #REF! when I set the 'C' column to 'Almost Certain'.

[Screenshot of excel workbook, with inset image of the scoring matrix for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1epCi.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you have mixed up the column and row reference within `INDEX()`. Try in `E5`:

```
=INDEX(Scoring!E$5:J$9,MATCH(D5,Scoring!D$5:D$9,0),MATCH(C5,Scoring!E$4:J$4,0))
```

Drag down.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response - but I think you're wrong?

In the table in the upper part of the screenshot. Column C (Possible, Highly Unlikely, Almost Certain, Highly Unlikely) is clearly referenced as "MATCH($C5,Scoring!$E$4:$J$4,)" and those corresponding entries can be clearly seen in Row 4 of the lower part of the screenshot.

If it was totally inverted, then the entries of 'Possible' ' Highly Likely' and 'Highly Unlikely' would also error would they not?

Comment: @RobBrown, a quick test on my end worked fine for your sample data. Have you tested it? FYI, I was talking about the row and column parameters of the `INDEX()` function. Meaning you just had to swap your `MATCH()` order.

Comment: Aaah - I had failed to understand your point. My thanks for your instruction. That has indeed worked!